# Cannot open a connection from a PC but the host can be reached from other computers

Tags: port, tcp, telnet

When I use telnet to try a port on a server, I get the following:

> > telnet x.x.x.x xxxx
> >
> > Connecting To x.x.x.x...Could not open connection to the host, on port xxxx: Connect failed

But if I try with a telnet tool on the web (for example http://www.adminkit.net/telnet.aspx) the connection can be opened successfully.

I assume the problem is in the local computer. I have tried turning off the firewall but that didn't help.

Which are the possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to answer this the best I can. First, it depends on the ip address you are trying to use. If both systems are on the same internal network, you should be trying the internal network ip and not the external. Secondly, if both systems are on the internal network, then its most likely the server is not listening on the local ip address which means which ever software you are using to handle telnet connections on the server needs to be set to listen on the appropriate addresses and ports or is not listening for incoming requests on the local network. Depending on the server, it could be a problem with the iptables(assuming server is Linux). If the server is not in the same internal network, then you most likely have a router firewall problem or need to open the port/forward the port that you are trying to telnet to in your router.

Comment: The server is in a different network. Do you mean I need to open the port in local computer?

Comment: if you have a software firewall, like windows firewall or other types of firewalls on local computer installed yes you will need to add the port there. If you have a router or modem that is also a router. They both generally have a firewall too, so it is necessary to log into them to add the port there as well.